# Extract date from string and insert into field Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, parsing, extract

Say I have a field UserAddedInfo with a string "User was added to the system and removed from list on 16/05/2016 by User Annon" and a field DateAdded in the same table.

Is there any way in SQL to extract that 16/05/2016 date from the string field and insert it into the DateAdded field as a datetime?

The date in the string is always going to be dd/MM/yyyy.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, its Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Do you know that's the EXACT format you'll always get?  Will the last 10 characters always be `dd/mm/yyyy`?  If not, please make clear what is known about that string.

Comment: If it's always at the end of the string you could use RIGHT(field, 10) to get the date and then convert it into a date

Comment: I updated the OP with some more info. The dates will always be dd/MM/yyyy and the string could have the date in any position

Comment: Since your only actual question is asking if this is possible the only actual viable answer is "YES". Since I am guessing you want an example, give us some sample data to work with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `PATINDEX` to get the start position of the date string in the column and extract 10 characters from that position. To convert the extracted string to `date`, use `CONVERT` with format `103`.

> 103 = dd/mm/yyyy

```
select 
convert(date,
substring(UserAddedInfo,patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo),10)
      ,103)
from table_name
where patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo) > 0
```

To update the dateadded field in the table, use

```
update table_name
set dateadded = convert(date,
substring(UserAddedInfo,patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo),10)
      ,103)
where patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo) > 0
```

Use `try_cast` or `try_convert` to return `null` when the substring returns invalid dates.

```
select 
try_cast(
substring(UserAddedInfo,patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo),10) 
as date) 
--or
--try_convert(date,
--substring(UserAddedInfo,patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo),10) 
--) 
from table_name
where patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo) > 0
```

Comment: Not that it's a huge deal but you could certainly narrow the matches a bit for a higher confidence it's truly a date that you're matching. For example: `%[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/20[0-9][0-9]%`

Comment: This one worked like a charm, I actually had put the where patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',UserAddedInfo) > 0 as I was trying your solution as there was some UserAdded Info in there with no date. Thank you very much for this answer! Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a note that you need to check the date format within the Patindex matches the string your looking at but worked very nicely!

Answer (score 0):

You can use patindex to find date string, and use cast to convert it to datetime

```
select 
    cast(substring('User was added to the system and removed from list on 27/08/2014 by User Annon', 
        patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 
                 'User was added to the system and removed from list on 27/08/2014 by User Annon'), 10) as datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, im going to give this a try now!

Comment: To whom marked the downvote, can you explain the reason?

Comment: I'm not downvoter but your query threw an error when I tried it. Safest thing is to specify the date format.

Comment: @shawnt00, thank you for the explanation. For US time it dis not give error. But safest way is to use convert, you're right.

Comment: I also wasnt the one who down voted, I appreciated the answer!